How to load data into Kendo grid using ajax call?
I am creating a spring boot application to book flights. I have defined a controller to retrieve flight details from database:
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/home")
public class FlightController {
    
    @Autowired
    private FlightService flightService;
    
    @GetMapping("/search")
    public String getFlights(
                @RequestParam("origin") String origin,
                @RequestParam("destination") String destination,
                Model model,
                HttpSession session) {
        
        List<Flight> flightList = flightService.getFightsByOriginAndDestination(origin, destination);
        
        if(flightList.isEmpty()) {
             model.addAttribute("message", "No flights available for the given origin and destination.");
             return "home";
        }
        else {
            model.addAttribute("flightList", flightList);
            model.addAttribute("username", session.getAttribute("username"));
            return "home";
        }
    }
}

Now, I want do display the details in a kendo grid by making an ajax call. I tried something like this, but it didn't work:
$(document).ready(function () {
                
    $.ajax({
        url: "/home/search",
        type: "GET",
        dataType: "local",

        success: function (data) {
                       
            $("#grid").kendoGrid({
                   dataSource: {
                        data: data,
                        pageSize: 10 
                   },
                   height: 550,
                   sortable: true,
                   pageable: true,
                   columns: [
                          { field: "flight_Number", title: "Flight Number" },
                          { field: "airline_Name", title: "Airline Name" },
                          { field: "departure", title: "Departure" },
                          { field: "arrival", title: "Arrival" },
                          { field: "date", title: "Date" },
                          { field: "price", title: "Price" }
                       
                   ]
            });
        },
        error: function (xhr, status, error) {
            console.error("Failed to fetch flight data:", error);
        }
    });
});

I know something is wrong, but I am unable to point out the issue. Can someone help?
